# Transformation of equation to isolate parameters

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the equation given by
\begin{equation}
y = ax+ e,
\end{equation}
where I like to transform the equation such that the parameter $a$ is isolated, which can be simply done by
\begin{equation}
\frac{y}{x} = a + \frac{e}{x}.
\end{equation}
Now, extend the first equation by adding a variable (and parameter), given by
\begin{equation}
y = a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + e.
\end{equation}
Any ideas how to transform this last equation such that the two parameters $a_1,a_2$ are isolated, just as shown for the simple case in the second equation?

The general purpose is to tansform the expression $y=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+e$ such that in the resulting expression $a_1$ and $a_2$ appear purly additive (but not multiplicative as in the case where $a_i \cdot x_i$, for $i=1,2$).

Comment: What exactly does it mean for $a_1$ and $a_2$ to be isolated at the same time?

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, that's it! If there is any possibility to achieve that $a_1$ and $a_2$ are isolated at the same time.

Comment: "Yes" does not answer my question. My question is, what are you trying to ask for?

Comment: My guess is that you're asking for something impossible. With that in mind, it might be helpful if you could explain *why* you want to isolate both parameters at the same time. What would this help you accomplish?

Comment: Trying to be more specific.  So my question is whether there is any way to transform the third equation in my post to achieve an expression like $something = a_1 + a_2 + something$, i.e. isolating $a_1$ and $a_2$ from the variables $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you're asking for. Presumably, you want the second "something" to be independent of $a_1$ and $a_2$. If that's the case, then as I suspected, you are asking for an impossible task.

Comment: Both the first and the second "something" should be independent of $a_1$ and $a_2$. But yes, if there is no way, then that's what it is.

Comment: The general purpose is to tansform the expression $y = a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 +e$ such that in the resulting expression $a_1$ and $a_2$ are purly additive (but not multiplicative as in the case $a_ix_i$, for $i = 1,2$).